# Spring Data Rest @HandleBeforeCreate method is not called

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have 2 classes. `Post` and `Comment`. Post `@HandleBeforeCreate` works fine but Comment `@HandleBeforeCreate` not. I wonder why?

PostEventHandler class:

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(Post.class)
public class PostEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void setPostAuthorname(Post Post) {
        System.out.println("This method called successfully!");
    }
}
```

PostRepository Interface:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "posts", path = "posts")
public interface PostRepository extends MongoRepository<Post, String> {

}
```

No custom Controller/Resource implementation for `Post` class. But In my Comments Repository interface I have a custom method and it looks like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "comments", path = "comments")
public interface CommentRepository extends MongoRepository<Comment, String> {
    // announceId is a field in Comment class. Get method works fine
    List<Comment> findAllByAnnounceId(String announceId);
}
```

CoomentEventHandler class:

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(Comment.class)
public class CommentEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void setCommentAuthorUsername(Comment comment) {
        System.out.println("This method never gets invoked!");
    }
}
```

Custom CommentController implementation:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class CommentController {

    @Autowired
    private AnnounceRepository announceRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CommentRepository commentRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/announces/{announceId}/comments", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Comment>> getAllComments(@PathVariable("announceId") String announceId) {
        System.out.println("This method called successfully with a valid PathVariable!);
        // Custom interface method works fine
        List<Comment> comments = commentRepository.findAllByAnnounceId(announceId);
        if (comments != null) {
            System.out.println("This method called successfully!);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(comments, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/announces/{announceId}/comments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Comment> createComment(@PathVariable("announceId") String announceId, @RequestBody Comment comment) {
        System.out.println("This method called successfully with a valid PathVariable and Comment object!");
        Announce announce = announceRepository.findOne(announceId);
        if (announce != null) {
            commentRepository.save(comment);
            announce.getCommentList().add(comment);
            announceRepository.save(announce);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Event Handlers (like @HandleBeforeCreate annotated methods) are only invoked when you fires a HTTP Request on exposed Spring Data REST endpoints. That's the reason why the POST request on /posts path triggers the setPostAuthorname method.
In the CommentController case, you are exposed custom request mapping methods, and invoking directly the method repositories, at this way, never will be triggered the event handlers. The only way that you hav using this approach is injecting the Event Handler Bean in your CommentController and invoke corresponding methods befor and afeter the invocation of save repository method, OR, invoking directly from the User Interface, I mean, from the client, and perform the logic of createComment method from UI, doing a POST request over the exposed /comments API path.

Regards.